# How to make a search that understands the essence of the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nlp, architecture, artificial-intelligence

The website has many categories, such as cars, parts, mobile phones, and real estate. The task is to create a search that understands the query and adjusts the filters for that query. This means that the search should not look for keywords in the title and description of the product, but should adjust the filters to find the desired product.

Here are a few examples:

- Red iPhone in Paris - the system should understand that the iPhone belongs to the mobile phone category, the manufacturer is Apple, the color red should also be selected in a separate filter, and in Paris, it should be related to the location filter, therefore we select the country France - Paris region.
- BMW E39 in Japan - the category is selected as cars, the manufacturer is BMW, the model is 5 series, the production year is 1996-2003, and the location is the country Japan.

Many other examples can be given, but I think the task is clear. All the characteristics of the products are in the database.

Currently, the task is to create search suggestions, that is, to transform the search query into several search options, one of which the user will select.

But the question is how to implement this technically? Elasticsearch is already used in the project, so I think it makes sense to create an index in it where all the characteristics of the products, places, and categories will be stored, and also add some custom queries that administrators will create.

Is this approach correct? If anyone has any ideas or experience in implementing such a task, I would appreciate any useful materials or advice!

UPDATE: I would also like to add that the website has many languages, and correcting grammatical errors in the search query is considered a separate task. Currently, we are only considering how to transform the query into filter settings.

Comment: you can start by [Natural language processing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/current/ml-nlp.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [facets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets-guide.html).  You can do a full-text search for the terms in elastic-search, and [then extract the facets (filters) for that search-term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets.html) so you can check the search values against the returned facets.

so when you search for "Red iPhone in Paris" and you get back a color facet with the value "Red", you would check that filter.  The challenge is when you also get the product name "Red Eye Reducer", you won't know that this isn't a double-highlight.  This is where NLP *could* help, knowing if it's an adjective vs a noun...  However with these short sentences and just the way people search are not necessarily conducive to accurate NLP.

Personally I'd try the brute-force way (matching facets to search terms) and see how it looks before trying something more nuanced.